# drop down menu, coding consistency with main navigational menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am not able to build a drop down menu based on my existing navigational css design.

here is the current nav code

```
                     <ul>
                        <li><a href="index" class="current">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="psat-sat-act-online-tutoring">Subjects &amp; Pricing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="how-online-tutoring-works">Get Started</a></li>
                        <li><a href="system-requirements">System Requirements</a></li>
                        <li><a href="faq-us">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>


                    </ul>
```

and css code

```
header h1 {background:url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat 0 0;padding:2px 0 0 38px;font-family:'ColaborateThinRegular';font-size:26px;line-height:1.2em;color:#fff;font-weight:normal;float:left}
header h1 a {color:#fff;text-decoration:none}
header h1 strong {font-family:'ColaborateBoldRegular';font-weight:normal}
header nav {padding:7px 0 10px 0}
header nav ul {float:right;padding:2px 0 0 0}
header nav ul li {float:left;padding-left:4px}
header nav ul li a {position:relative;float:left;font-size:12px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;font-family:'ColaborateThinRegular';text-transform:uppercase;height:32px;line-height:32px;background-color:#181717;padding:0 36px 0 10px;border-radius:17px;-moz-border-radius:17px;-webkit-border-radius:17px}
header nav ul li a:hover, header nav ul li a.current {background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ee3c09, #b90a09);/* FF3.6 */background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #ee3c09),color-stop(1, #b90a09));/* Saf4+, Chrome */filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr= '#ee3c09', endColorstr= '#b90a09');/* IE6,IE7 */-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr= '#ee3c09', endColorstr= '#b90a09')";/* IE8 */}
header nav ul li a:after {content:'';display:block;position:absolute;right:12px;top:13px;width:4px;height:7px;background:url(../images/arrow1.gif) no-repeat 0 0}
header .adv-content {overflow:hidden;background:#f9f9f9;padding:10px 0 8px 0}
header .breadcrumbs {float:left;padding:3px 0 0 10px}
header .breadcrumbs li {display:inline;color:#212121;padding-left:5px}
```

Under the get started tab, i would like to add a multi level drop down menu..all assistance is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the class names in the HTML elements.
You will also need to add a new unordered list to each li you want to have a drop down.

```
<div id="header">
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index" class="current">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="psat-sat-act-online-tutoring">Subjects &amp; Pricing</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="how-online-tutoring-works">Get Started</a>
        <ul id="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="system-requirements">System Requirements</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq-us">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

You will then need to add this to your CSS.

```
ul.nav ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 598;
}   
ul.nav li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Hi i've defined header and nav like this <header>
  <nav>.. and the css is making the nav drop down popup to the right of parent menu rather than under it.. any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: Please can you copy your code into http://jsfiddle.net/ so I can see it and fix it? Then click "save" and send me to the URL. 
Thanks

Comment: You can move the dropdown with the following code.
`ul.nav ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 598;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 170px;
}   `

Please try the following: 
http://jsfiddle.net/N6rtb/1/

Comment: hi, here is the jsfiddle as you asked for http://jsfiddle.net/qR82f/1/  thanks a lot for the help